# python requests only returning empty sets when scraping .htm page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am attempting to scrape a `.htm` link and cannot get my script to return anything besides `'[]'`.

link = https://www.forwardhealth.wi.gov/WIPortal/StaticContent/Member/caseloads/481-caseload.htm

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

link = 'https://www.forwardhealth.wi.gov/WIPortal/StaticContent/Member/caseloads/481-caseload.htm'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')      #I've tried other html parsers in here as well as r.content
```

I believe the issue lies in my attempt to interact with the page (possibly incorrect encoding?). The above format is how I've always set up any web-scraping performed in the past and haven't had any issues that I couldn't address. What stands out the most is when I call `r.content` or `r.text` I get a response that seems foreign:

`'<HTML>\r\n<HEAD>\r\n<TITLE>481-caseload</TITLE>\r\n<META NAME="GENERATOR" CONTENT="Microsoft FrontPage 5.0">\r\n<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">\r\n</HEAD>\r\n\r\n<FRAMESET ROWS="*,48" FRAMESPACING="0" FRAMEBORDER="no" BORDER="0">\r\n<FRAME NAME="ReportArea" SRC="481-caseload/by_county_tribe/by_county_tribe.htm"\r\n MARGINWIDTH="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" SCROLLING="no" FRAMEBORDER="0" NORESIZE>\r\n<FRAMESET COLS="*" FRAMESPACING="0" FRAMEBORDER="0" BORDER="0">\r\n<FRAME NAME="ReportLinks" SRC="481-caseload/DocLinks.htm" FRAMEBORDER="0" MARGINWIDTH="2" MARGINHEIGHT="3" scrolling="auto">\r\n</FRAMESET></FRAMESET></HTML>'`

This makes me think that my script isn't properly written to handle whatever this is above. I've never seen "Microsoft FrontPage 5.0" before and don't know if that might be what's throwing off my code. I've tried forcing an encoding by changing `r.encoding = #encoding here`. Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the page consists of multiple nested [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)s - basically, separate pages with its own URLs loaded by the browser when the main "container" page is loaded. Use browser developer tools to inspect the page and see in what `iframe` your desired content is located.

The main content of this page is coming from the [this url](https://www.forwardhealth.wi.gov/WIPortal/StaticContent/Member/caseloads/481-caseload/by_county_tribe/0.htm):

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: url = "https://www.forwardhealth.wi.gov/WIPortal/StaticContent/Member/caseloads/481-caseload/by_county_tribe/0.htm"

In [4]: response = requests.get(url)

In [5]: soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

In [6]: soup.select_one("td.s2").get_text()
Out[6]: 'Wisconsin Medicaid'
```